I'm opening an .exe file to see if the mods are working correctly and this appeared, something else was supposed to appear
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
What should I do?
It was supposed to look like this: Mods Loaded in C:\Users\Usuário\Downloads\STARDEW VALLEY - VERSÃO 1.5.6 HOTFIX #3\Mods. or something like that, but that thing is appearing and I don't know what to do
